# how to split data using a [nn] pattern into sentences

Tags: python, regex

problem:  split txt into sentences using the pattern [nn].   The end result is 10 sentences.   Lookbehind gives me 10 sentences but I miss the [nn] in the sentence.  Look ahead gives me 9 sentences, I miss the last sentence.  I need to include the pattern [nn] in the sentence

```
txt="[01] Final Step - Protonica [02] Liquid Frequencies (Liquid Soul Mix) - Liquid Soul [03] Global Illumination - Liquid Soul [04] Devotion - Liquid Soul [05] Black Rock City - Quantize [06] Plazza Del Trripy - Andromeda [07] Private Guide - Suntree [08] Stereo Gun - Vibrasphere [09] The Cycle - Ritree [10] Atmonizer - Andromed"
```

I used a lookahead to find a match. I am missing the last sentence.

```
print(".+? is the ungreedy character match")
#print("(?<=\[\d{2}\]) is the lookbehind character match")
print("(?=\[\d{2}\]) is the lookforward character match")
#pattern=r"(?<=\[\d{2}\]).+?(?=\[\d{2}\])"
pattern=r".+?(?=\[\d{2}\])"
matches=re.findall(pattern,txt)
for match in matches:
    print("output",match)
output:

output [01] Final Step - Protonica 
output [02] Liquid Frequencies (Liquid Soul Mix) - Liquid Soul 
output [03] Global Illumination - Liquid Soul 
output [04] Devotion - Liquid Soul 
output [05] Black Rock City - Quantize 
output [06] Plazza Del Trripy - Andromeda 
output [07] Private Guide - Suntree 
output [08] Stereo Gun - Vibrasphere 
output [09] The Cycle - Ritree
```

Missing

```
output [10] Atmonizer - Andromed
```

Comment: You can use `re.split(r'(?!^)(?=\[\d{2}])', text)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lgHNIX/1).

Comment: You can use `\[\d+].*?(?=\[\d+]|$)` https://regex101.com/r/hiMwTO/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a lookahead to find a match with |$ to find the last sentence

```
print(".+? is the ungreedy character match")
print("(?=\[\d{2}\]) is the lookforward character match")
pattern="\[\d{2}\].+?(?=\[\d{2}\]|$)"
matches=re.findall(pattern,txt)
for match in matches:
    print("output",match)
```

output:

```
output [01] Final Step - Protonica 
output [02] Liquid Frequencies (Liquid Soul Mix) - Liquid Soul 
output [03] Global Illumination - Liquid Soul 
output [04] Devotion - Liquid Soul 
output [05] Black Rock City - Quantize 
output [06] Plazza Del Trripy - Andromeda 
output [07] Private Guide - Suntree 
output [08] Stereo Gun - Vibrasphere 
output [09] The Cycle - Ritree 
output [10] Atmonizer - Andromed
```

Answer (score 0):

Often you can avoid a lookahead and just find characters until *not* the next one

```py
>>> re.findall(r"\[[^\[]+", txt)
['[01] Final Step - Protonica ', '[02] Liquid Frequencies (Liquid Soul Mix) - Liquid Soul ', '[03] Global Illumination - Liquid Soul ', '[04] Devotion - Liquid Soul ', '[05] Black Rock City - Quantize ', '[06] Plazza Del Trripy - Andromeda ', '[07] Private Guide - Suntree ', '[08] Stereo Gun - Vibrasphere ', '[09] The Cycle - Ritree ', '[10] Atmonizer - Andromed']
```

This works by finding `[` and then greedily any characters which are *not* `[` (which starts the next block)

This approach will work for your current input, but won't work if there are further `[` characters in a grouping you wish to find; in which case you should likely search for the whole block with `-` or correct the input such that it will strip those characters for you